# How does `du` count blocks used

Tags: disk-usage

I'm curious to understand how `du` counts blocks used in a file.

Scenario

```
dd bs=1 seek=2GiB if=/dev/null of=big
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 2.3324e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s

ls -lh big
-rw-r--r-- 1 roaima roaima 2.0G May 19 15:55 big

du -h big
0       big
```

I've always accepted that it will give me different answers to `ls`, and that's fine because they're measuring different things.

Now I have a cloud based filesystem where I get charged not only for storage but also each time I download data, so I need to minimise the amount of data accessed by general housekeeping activities such as "how much disk space is used in this tree?"

I'm not aware of a library/system call to tell me the number of used blocks, although there could easily be one. I don't believe `du` reads its way through every file it's considering because that doesn't differentiate between a file filled with zeros and one that's truly sparse.

So, how does `du` count blocks used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`du` uses [`stat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to find the number of blocks used by a file. If you run `stat big` you should see that the number of blocks matches the number given by `du`.

You can force `du` to count bytes using the `-b` option; then its output matches `ls`'s.

In both cases it uses `stat(2)` (or rather, `fstatat(2)` at least in the version I have):

```
$ strace du big|&grep big
execve("/usr/bin/du", ["du", "big"], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "big", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2147483648, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
write(1, "0\tbig\n", 60 big
```

The difference in processing is [visible in `du.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/du.c#n588).

Comment: So it does. I use `stat(1)` regularly but had not realised it could give me blocks used. (I guess I wasn't looking for it so just didn't see it...)

Comment: And, conversely, you should be able to match `du`'s output using \`ls` by doing `ls -lsh big` which will print the blocks in the first column.